# Can I use the after pseudo class for creating target image?

Tags: css

So I've got this css here:

```
.outerDot {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.outerDot:after {
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

And I want the `.outerDot:after` to show up inside the `.outerDot`. Am I barking up the wrong tree?  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hV93X/)

The html is just `<div class="outerDot"></div>`.

Comment: You haven't specified any content, and you're missing some `;`s.

Comment: What exactly is the intended result?

Comment: @Jon To get the .outerDot:after to show up at all would be nice, but I want to make the whole think look like a target.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a `content` attribute, and make it display block:

```
.outerDot:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hV93X/2/

Comment: @watson - Because that's what the `:before` & `:after` pseudo elements were originally designed for: to add visual content to your HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by visual content, like images?